# Getting error message when trying to save options in Redux Framework

Tags: wordpress

When anything changes from the Redux and clicks the save change then showing this warning message “There was an error with your action. Please try later or reload the page”

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser output console (CTRL+SHIFT+I). At the top of the string in the console will be whatever output is causing that message. You'll then need to comment out whatever echo, print_r, etc is causing it.
If it's something like this,

**"Failed to load resources: the server responded with a status of http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not found)"**

this is your wordpress issue.